# SLES Devel Packages?

Tags: linux, opensuse, repository, sles, dev

It seems SLES 11.2 (and OpenSUSE) are missing many devel (dev) packages common in other distros such as Ubuntu Server or CentOS.  I understand that packages / deps may be wrapped up in other-named SLES packages, but it's difficult to track down, especially if you're coming from those other distros, which I am.

http://software.opensuse.org/developer/en isn't much help in this regard.

Can someone recommend a good source (or sources) for dev related packages for SLES?  Perhaps its something simple I'm overlooking.  Of course Googling around you can find numerous (shady) sites with RPMs and such but of course something more "official" would be ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for SDKs. Go to [Suse downloads](https://download.suse.com/index.jsp), select `SUSE Linux Enterprise Software Development Kit` and the version you want.

If you want just the dev-rpms, DVD 1 is enough. DVD 2 contains the source-rpms for these rpms.

Comment: How to get  zlib.h for SLES 11? Start with downloading  several GB of iso images and then... Don't you see something is deeply wrong here?

Comment: @Dawid Toton: In an enterprise environment you will have internal repo servers for dozens of servers. And then you sync the update-repos, too.